# We use an 'Upgraded Custom Audience Pixel', why is Facebook doing a callback whenever an action is performed on my website

Tags: facebook, tracking

I'm using Facebook's 'Upgraded Custom Audience Pixel' (connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js) and I've just noticed that each time an action is performed on my website, such as using a `<select>`, or clicking on a button, then there's a callback to Facebook. For example, when I interact with a `<select>` on the website it sends:

```
https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=THEID&ev=SubscribedButtonClick&dl=https%3A%2F%2FTHEURL&rl=https%3A%2F%2FTHEURL&if=false&ts=THETS&cd[buttonText]=None%C2%A0&cd[buttonFeatures]=%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22tag%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22classList%22%3A%22btn%20dropdown-toggle%20selectpicker%20btn-default%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%2C%22innerText%22%3A%22None%C2%A0%22%2C%22imageUrl%22%3Anull%2C%22numChildButtons%22%3A0%2C%22destination%22%3A%22%22%7D&cd[formFeatures]=%5B%5D&cd[pageFeatures]=%7B%22title%22%3A%22PAGETITLT%22%7D&sw=1280&sh=1024&v=2.8.37&r=stable&ec=4&o=30&fbp=fb.2.1547380815932.2118539582&it=1547380828361&coo=false&es=automatic
```

It seems to report back the URL, the name/id of the select box, what option was selected, page title, and other metrics. What is this, and why is Facebook tracking user interactions on my website like this?

It seems a little intrusive, given I don't recall giving Facebook permission to track this level of interaction.

Comment: I haven't used the upgraded FB pixel, only the basic audience pixel.  However, it appears to be doing what it's supposed to based on what I read here:  https://www.jonloomer.com/2015/07/16/facebook-upgraded-pixel/  Isn't the purpose of the "upgraded" FB pixel to track events/interaction rather than just pages?